# How can I use Garamond Premier Pro's own glyphs for e.g. square root in mathmode (using lualatex)?

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math

I'm using lualatex (TeXlive 2019) and the font Garamond Premier Pro, which
(shown in the screenshot, taken using fontforge) provides special glyphs for the following mathematical symbols:
n-array product, summation, square-root and integral.

[image]

Disclaimer: I know, that the unicode-math package documentation does not mention Garamond Premier Pro support. Nevertheless, that's what I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{Cambria Math} %<-- this works fine, of course.
\setmainfont{GaramondPremrPro}[%
  Extension = .otf ,
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Numbers={Lining,Proportional},
  Ligatures={TeX,Common,NoRare},
]

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{-1}$

$\int_a^b f(x)dx$

\end{document}
```

Question:
How can I use Garamond Premier Pro's own glyphs for e.g. square root in mathmode using lualatex?

Comment: I would avoid it. Using symbols from text fonts is okay for the occasional use in text, but for real math better use a real math font.Try e.g. garamond-math.

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding garamond-math, But, my question aims just for occasional use.

Comment: search the site for examples for the range option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Got it, at least partial: `\setmathfont{GaramondPremrPro}[range={"222B}]` uses GPP's integral symbol. But I can't find the proper range for GPP's lining figures. Do you have another hint for me? Thanks a lot!